# correct use of the command FindInstance

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, syntax, resolve

I have tried to solve this system for numbers that go from 1 to 10 non-repeated integers, this occurs to me

```
 FindInstance[
 a + b == c + d + e + f == g + h == i + j == a + c + g + i == 
 b + f + h + i && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > e > 0 && f > 0 && 
 g > 0  && h > 0 && i > 0 && j > 0, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}]
```

but I get nothing. One of the main aspects is how to indicate that the variables must be different (from 1 to 10 it is simple, but from 1 to 100 I cannot imagine)
thanks for any help

**Edit (Bill's suggestion)
I have reformulated the problem and it works well, I just need to know which of all those results give me the maximum sum**

```
 **Needs["Combinatorica`"]; p = 
 Range[10]; Do[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} = 
 p = NextPermutation[p]; 
 If[a + b +  c + d == b + e + f + h == g + h + i + j, Print[p]], {10!}]**
```

Comment: `... b > 0 c > 0...`?

Comment: `b > 0 c > 0 ` makes the expression `False`. Presumably, you mean `b > 0 && c > 0 `. However, the result is then `{ }` which indicates that there is no valid solution.

Comment: Try `Needs["Combinatorica\`"]; p=Range[10]; Do[ {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}=p= NextPermutation[p]; If[a+b==c+d+e+f==g+h,Print[p]], {10!}]` and ignore the caution about Combinatorica loading. After looking at that result insert the extra `==i+j` condition and try it again. This avoids wondering whether `FindInstance` just didn't try hard enough and avoids `0<a<11&&0<b<11&&...` (IF you have enough memory you can modify this to generate all the permutations first, but you will never be able to buy enough memory to hold 100! permutations while you can just wait longer for `NextPermutation` to find one)

Comment: @Bill , Thanks, see my edition please

Comment: @Bob Hanlon  , thanks for your indication

Comment: Does this work for you? `Needs["Combinatorica\`"]; p=Range[10]; max=-Infinity;
Do[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}=p=NextPermutation[p]; If[a+b+c+d==b+e+f+h==g+h+i+j, If[max<a+b+c+d,max=a+b+c+d;best=p]],{10!}];best` Might want to stick an extra `Print` in there, just so you can feel it is making progress.

Comment: I think it works well, but as you say you need a flag that tells me how the search is going

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Combinatorica`"];

p = Range[10];

sol = {};

Do[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} = p = NextPermutation[p];
 If[a + b + c + d == b + e + f + h == g + h + i + j, 
  sol = Append[sol, p]], {10!}]
```

The number of solutions is

```
Length@sol

(* 7200 *)
```

The greatest sum is

```
max = Max[Total /@ sol[[All, 1 ;; 4]]]

(* 24 *)
```

The solutions with the greatest sum are

```
sol2 = Select[sol, Total[#[[1 ;; 4]]] == max &];
```

The number of these solutions is

```
Length@sol2

(* 1152 *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
And @@ (
  Total[#[[1 ;; 4]]] == Total[#[[{2, 5, 6, 8}]]] ==
     Total[#[[7 ;; 10]]] == max & /@ sol2)

(* True *)
```

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: but as you can see the list of the numbers that meet this sum